# Ract-Admin: How can i fix the version of react-admin and its dependencies?

Tags: react-admin

In my `package.json` I have fixed the version of the main-package but its dependencies are not the same.

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "react-admin": "2.0.4"
}
```

But in my `node_modules` I have `react-core: "2.3.0"` and `ra-ui-materialui: "2.3.0"` ...

Answer (score 2):

Add the sub-dependencies in your `package.json` with your version requirements:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "react-admin": "2.0.4",
    "ra-core": "2.0.4",
    ...
}
```

npm will be smart enough to use the version you specified as dependency of react-admin.

By the way, use a `package.lock` or a `yarn.lock`, so updates in dependencies don't change your code.